# Building Libzip on MacOS with Cmake unable to find right package

Tags: macos, cmake, macos-high-sierra, libzip

I'm building libzip [version 1.7.3]. The package uses CMake.

I do the following as initial setup:

```
wget -c https://github.com/nih-at/libzip/releases/download/v1.7.3/libzip-1.7.3.tar.gz
tar -zxf libzip-1.7.3.tar.gz
cd libzip-1.7.3
mkdir build && cd build
```

And then I run the following:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

However, Cmake seems unable to find libbz2 as I get the following among the list of messages:

```
-- Found BZip2: /Library/Frameworks/libbz2.framework (found version "1.0")
```

I had previously installed libbz2 [and other dependencies like GnuTLS, Nettle, XZ, etc.] in `/usr/local`, and I can verify that `libbz2.dylib` is in `/usr/local/lib`.

I've tried setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` speifically to `/usr/local`. And I've also tinkered with `FindBZip2.cmake`, but I'm not a CMake expert so I didn't go beyond changing variable assignments [specifically forcing `/usr/local` to no avail].

It only works when I delete `libbz2.framework`, but that isn't a workable solution.

Is there way around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_IGNORE_PATH=/Library/Frameworks -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

See cmake docs on [CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH.html) for more information.

Comment: Setting the variable `CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH` from the command line (with `-D` option for `cmake`) contradicts **intention** of the variable. The documentation states that "it is intended to be set by the project".

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes. However, this is an ideal expectation. Given the differences between various UNIX platforms, and perhaps the project's inability to test all platforms in various circumstances, not every issue in installation can be envisaged beforehand.